# Parsing JSON Response Issue with escape characters

Tags: apex, integration, json, parser, escape

Below is the response from an external system. In Salesforce, I need to save the value of **test1**. Now JSON Parser it trying to destruct the **test1** value also because it has escape character before the double quotes. When I try to replace the \" with \\", it is replacing all the quotes with \\" instead of replacing the **test1** value.  Is there any other alternative way to parse this JSON Response?

```
String s = '{   "test1": " {\"test3\":[{\"firstId\":\"Id1\"}]}",    "test2" : "test2" }';
//This line throws an error since parser is trying to destruct the test1 value also.
//Map<String, Object> deserializedString = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUnTyped(s);

//There won't be any slash in the output.
System.debug('s value ++ '+ s);
//s value ++ {  "test1": " {"test1":[{"firstId":"Id1"}]}",  "test2" : "test2" }

//It will replace all the double quotes with slash and double quotes. I just need to add an extra slash to the test1 value.
System.debug('After Replacing++ '+ s.replace('\"','\\"'));
//After Replacing++ {   \"test1\": \" {\"test1\":[{\"firstId\":\"Id1\"}]}\",    \"test2\" : \"test2\" }
```

Comment: It will work if the JSON value "test1": " {\"test1\":[{\"firstId\":\"Id1\"} doesn't have any escape characters. Parser it trying to destruct " {\"test1\":[{\"firstId\":\"Id1\"} into a json object instead of considering that as a string.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). In your code you are using `test1` twice, so it is unclear to me which **test1** you are referring to when you say you *"just need to add an extra slash to the test1 value."* Could you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357221/edit) your question to rename the first `test1` in your code to something else, and then - if needed - change any references to **test1** in your question. I think that will help make clearer what exactly you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Moonpie.